# Zepto.js selector performance vs jquery

Tags: jquery, performance, zepto

I did see some test indicating that the id and class selector ($(#id); $(.class)) is slower than the jquery one.

I was wondering:

1. Is the difference significant? (noticeable)
2. Is the difference noticeable only if using it in a loop / selecting many elements?

I am thinking about switching to zepto for my desktop app since I only need modern webkit and firefox support anyway.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link to the test?

Comment: Nope, I was wondering if somebody else may have done extensive testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this jsperf test that indicates that the speed difference is significant:
http://jsperf.com/qwery-vs-jquery-vs-mootools-selector-engines/11

Answer (score 3):

it was solved now ;)

https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/issues/486

zepto use native browsers solution as fast as posible.

Answer (score 0):

Zepto only supports modern browsers so I can't see why it would be slower than jQuery

$(#id) and $(.class) map to the native browser methods getElementByID, getElementByClass in Zepto (and for modern browsers too in jQuery)

I guess the only way to know for sure is to run a test...

Comment: And that was done... http://www.codefessions.com/2012/08/performance-of-jquery-compatible-mobile.html